# Mocking a non database backed model in Rails with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, rspec2

I am trying to create a non ActiveRecord model in my Ruby on Rails application according to http://railscasts.com/episodes/121-non-active-record-model. I am facing hard time testing it though.

I have following class in my `app/models/sms.rb` file.

```
class Sms
  def initialize
    # Do stuff here
  end

  def deliver
    # Do some stuff here
  end
end
```

I am unable to mock deliver method on my Sms class.

```
it 'should do someting' do
  @sms = mock(Sms)
  @sms.should_receive(:deliver).and_return(true)

  post :create, :user_id => @user.id
  flash[:notice].should == "SMS sent successfully."
  response.should redirect_to(some_url)
end
```

In my controller code I do have a line that says `@sms.deliver`. Yet above gives following error:

```
   Failure/Error: @sms.should_receive(:deliver).and_return(true)
      (Mock Sms).deliver(any args)
      expected: 1 time
      received: 0 times
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Variables beginning with @ are instance variables. The @sms your controller refers to is not the same @sms as your spec has defined.

Try changing

```
@sms = mock(Sms)
@sms.should_receive(:deliver).and_return(true)
```

to

```
Sms.any_instance.should_receive(:deliver).and_return(true)
```

Comment: Thanks Andy for your response. The `any_instance` method is available in Rspec 2.6 and above. I am using 2.0.0. I was able to solve this issue by tweaking my test code and a little discussion on #RubyOnRails. Above however also solves the problem but only in Rspec >=2.6.

Answer (score 2):

If your version of RSpec doesn't have the `any_instance` method, you'll need to stub `:new` on the class:

```
@sms = mock(Sms)
Sms.stub(:new).and_return(@sms)
@sms.should_receive(:deliver).and_return(true)
```